# How to draw multiple curved poly line between two locations in leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I want to create multiple curved polylines between two locations in leaflet. I have tried arc.js, but unable to get the result. Please suggest any option.

I have added the below code for creating curved lines

```
polyline.on('click', function (e) {
                for (var i = 1; i <= paths.length; i++) {
                    var curve = L.Polyline.Arc([polylinePoints[0].lat, polylinePoints[0].lng], [polylinePoints[1].lat, polylinePoints[1].lng], {
                        color: 'blue',
                        vertices: i*350 

                    })
                    pathMap.addLayer(curve);
                }
            })
```

But I am not getting curved lines in the map,I am getting the below result
[image]

Comment: One option would be, to show us what you've done and what exactly went wrong/doesn't work/doesn't fit *the* result. "unable to get the result" is a poor error description.

Comment: Given the scale you're working, I'm gonna guess you don't want to display curves, but [geodetic lines](https://github.com/henrythasler/Leaflet.Geodesic) instead.

Comment: Yes exactly @IvanSanchez ,but I want to draw multiple lines between two points

Comment: So... calculate the middle points yourself? How it the result supposed to look like?